# How to show a Customized MessageBox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, dll, portable-class-library

I want to show something like MessageBox in my windows 8 phone App, Unfortunately I am not able to find a way to do it.

```
Test.Show("Desc", "Title");
```

and my method in DLL

```
public static class Test
{
    public static void Show(object buttonsContent, object title)
    {

    }
}
```

- Please There are more things than this...*

How can I show my `Customized MessageBox` in class library in APP.....

Comment: How about `MessageBox.Show`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms598690(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Message Box work with only Strings... I wanna show buttons, Images and stuff.... is there any ?

Comment: Very good question. Its been asked very very precisely and it showed that you seriously tried to work yourself into the matter...

Comment: Thanks [BionicCode](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3141792/bioniccode)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup

Answer (score 1):

You can Try Either  [Advanced MessageBox for Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Advanced_MessageBox_for_Windows_Phone)  or  [CustomMessageBox from the Windows Phone Toolkit](http://shawnoster.com/2012/10/welcome-custommessagebox-to-the-windows-phone-toolkit/)

Answer (score 0):

Because in this example that you've given us you are passing two String objects to the `Show(object, object)` method, you could just use `MessageBox.Show(String, String, MessageBoxButton)` to show a dialog.

But if you intend to show something other than text in the MessageBox, then you have to implement a dialog view yourself. This can be done quite easily using the `PopUp` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup). It will custom content on top of the existin view into which you can place your content along with dialog buttons, that you then can handle.

Comment: Yeah but how do i make and show show popup in my app..? I cannot add it to layout...!

Comment: Popups are per design controls that will take up the entire screen, just like MessageBoxes. You need to add your PopUp control to the layout tree, so that you can set its IsOpen property to true (showing it) or false (hiding it) from C#. They are not part of any layout on the page (just like MessageBoxes are also not). Here's an example: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Pop-Ups_in_Windows_Phone

Answer (score 0):

You can easily re-style the `CustomMessageBox` control of the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) 
. 
You need to open a .xaml file in Blend and edit a copy of the style of a `CustomMessageBox`, so you can use it in your own projects. You can add your own content within the `ControlTemplate` of this style. You then copy this style to a place where you can access it, in the example below I put it in the `App.xaml` file.
You declare the `CustomMessageBox` like this:

```
new CustomMessageBox
   {
        Caption = "A messagebox",
        Style = App.Current.Resources["YourEditedStyleKey"] as Style,
   }.Show();
```

You can control the TemplateBinding on various properties that you can set on the CustomMessageBox. For example, you can set a custom font

```
FontFamily = App.Current.Resources["MuseoSans500"] as FontFamily,
```

And use a template binding in your custom style to use this font:

```
FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
```

Comment: Actually, I have check Toolkit as well as RadControls from Telerik... The thing is I do not want to rely on a 3rd party when I have chance to build it....! Thanks Anyway..If You have any other please let me know thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ChildWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class that provides a window that can be displayed over a parent window.

you can check example [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/how-to-implement-childwindow-in-windows-phone-7/)

Comment: That would be used only in Windows Phone 7, Correct me if I'm Wrong.. Thanks

Comment: No,you can use it in WP8 also.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a popup control on XAML design page like this

```
   <Popup x:Name="_Popup">
   <Border  Margin="30,190,24,194" CornerRadius="17" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="White" Opacity="0.9">
   <Grid x:Name="MsgPanel" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="250">
    <TextBlock Name="txtTitle" Text="Message" Foreground="Black" FontSize="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Calibri" Height="39" VerticalAlignment="Top" /> 
   <Border Margin="6,70,6,105" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="17" BorderThickness="3">
     <TextBox Name="txtmsgMobNo" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" MaxLength="10" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Courier New" FontWeight="Bold">
     </TextBox>
     </Border>
    <Border Margin="58,150,222,40" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="3" Background="Silver" BorderBrush="Gray">
    <Button Name="btnMsgSend" Content="Send" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" Height="68" Width="144" Click="btnMsgSend_Click" Margin="0,-10,0,0"></Button>
     </Border>
     </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

And in the code behind wherever you want to open the popup, put
        _Popup.Isopen = true;

Comment: Im looking for something that I do not have to enter seperately to visual tree. I want something like Messagebox that could popup any time.... and i want that to come from a dll file...>! but thanks anyway,.... Is there Any?